# How to deploy centrally managed Infopath forms with reusable workflows to a new environment

Tags: workflow, infopath, deployment

I am looking for a way  of deploying solutions based on infopath and reusable workflows  through development, test and production in a consistent manner. Can anyone outline a robust approach to  the above?

In a nut shell deploying centrally managed infopath forms to a site collection creates the required site columns and a content type. If you then create a reusable workflow against that  content type it does not appear to  be actually reusable. This seems to be because   when deployed to a new site the ID of the content type created when the centrally  managed form is activated will be different.

I have tried creating the site columns and content type as a feature. However I cannot get  the Infopath form to bind to the content type at activation

Has anyone actually made this work?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is it:

Create a web level feature to deploy site columns and a content type referencing the Infopath form you intend to  use. 
Publish the inform path form as a centrally managed template, promoting values to the new site columns.
Create a reusable  SharePoint designer workflow against the new content type.  Save as a template.

Deployment steps.

1. Deploy the content type feature
2. Upload the reusable workflow to the site solution gallery. Activate it in Site features for the target site
3. Create a new Form library .
4. Upload your infopath .xsn to  centrally managed form templates
5. Modify the new Form Library. From advanced settings Allow management of content types, select complete in browser. Remove the Form content type and add your new custom content type.
6. Edit the workflow associations for the new library to reference the workflow.